# Is there an automated way to install python modules (à la rubygems)?

Tags: python

I'm new to python. Are there alternatives to downloading a tarball for a python module & installing it via python setup install ? Anything like rubygems?

**UPDATE** I'm surprised that there are so many solutions for this one problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options - you can stick with your system's default packaging system (if it has one) or you can pick one (or more) of existing Python tools like `easy_install`, `zc.buildout` or `pip`. I would recommend you to use [Distribute](http://packages.python.org/distribute/) together with `pip`.

Answer (score 4):

[setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) is one option. Install that and then you can install many Python modules using the `easy_install` command-line tool.

Comment: The setuptools page mentions easy_install & I find this confusing. Are they the same thing ?

Comment: setuptools is a Python package you can install. easy_install is a command-line tool that gets installed as part of setuptools. So you just need to install setuptools.

Answer (score 1):

`easy_install` or `pip`. I also recommend checking out `virtualenv` to isolate environments for test running packages. The Python Package Index([pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi), also called Cheeseshop) is the official third-party software repository for Python.

Answer (score 1):

[Pip](http://pip.openplans.org/) is great:

```
$ pip install some_python_module
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
$ cat requirements.txt
```

Output from freeze:

```
Creoleparser==0.7.3
Django==1.3
Genshi==0.6
PIL==1.1.7
South==0.7.3
django-debug-toolbar==0.8.5
....
```

After this in any other place:

```
$ pip install < requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/)